# Add custom column names to Sendgrid list through API

Tags: sendgrid

I have tried using SnedGrid Marketing Email API for creating lists:
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/lists.html#-add

It works fine when creating a list with default columns, but I simply cannot find the right format for sending additional column names (e.g. user_id)
I have tried the "default" columnname=foo, and few other variations, but end up each time with only default columns, despite the reponse telling me about how succesful I am:

```
{"message": "success"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a documentation issue on our end. **First, let me deeply apologize for the inconvenience, this will be fixed shortly.**

Custom column names do not show up upon list creation. Only once an email has been added with a new column will that show up. *However*, this means you may arbitrarily add columns as necessary.

To create an email with any additional columns you may want, you'll use the [Add Email Endpoint](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html#-add), as such:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json \
     -d data={"email" : "nick@sendgrid.com", "name" : "Nick", "favorite" : "Loon"}
```

This call will create a new column named `favorite`.

Comment: Alright. This documentation issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/sendgrid/docs/pull/575). Thanks and sorry once again for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply, I appreciate your help.